# I cannot load the map platform in my android app, and just the logo is shown

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, neshan-platform, neshan-map

I want to use the Neshan map platform in my android app. but the map does not load on the emulator and just the logo is shown.

this is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.neshantest2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity android:name=".routing.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the gradle project level:
Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/neshan/neshan-android-sdk" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is the gradle module level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.neshantest2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
 }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:mobile-sdk:0.9.5'



    ///////////retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'

}
```

this is the main activity class:

```
package com.example.neshantest2.routing

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import com.example.neshantest2.R
import com.example.neshantest2.services.dataServices
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.neshan.core.Bounds
import org.neshan.core.LngLat
import org.neshan.core.LngLatVector
import org.neshan.core.Range
import org.neshan.geometry.LineGeom
import org.neshan.graphics.ARGB
import org.neshan.layers.VectorElementLayer
import org.neshan.services.NeshanMapStyle
import org.neshan.services.NeshanServices
import org.neshan.styles.*
import org.neshan.vectorelements.Line


const val BASE_MAP_INDEX = 0

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
RoutingInterface.RoutingViewInterface{
    var presenter: RoutingInterface.RoutingPresenterInterface? = null
    private lateinit var lineLayer: VectorElementLayer
    private lateinit var markerLayer: VectorElementLayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        presenter = RoutingPresenter(applicationContext,this)   //initial 
presenter
    }

    fun requestBtnClicked(view: View?) {
        //add origin and dest coordinates
        dataServices.originCoordinates = Pair(originx.text.toString(), originy.text.toString())
        dataServices.destinationCoordinates = Pair(destinationX.text.toString(), destinationY.text.toString())
        //add waypoints
        dataServices.waypoints += Pair(waypoint1x.text.toString(), waypoint1y.text.toString())
        dataServices.waypoints += Pair(waypoint2x.text.toString(), waypoint2y.text.toString())
        dataServices.waypoints += Pair(waypoint3x.text.toString(), waypoint3y.text.toString())
        //call APIs
        presenter!!.sendDistanceReq()
        presenter!!.sendDirectionReq()
        showmapbutton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun showRoutesClicked(view: View?) {
        mapInit()
        drawRoute()
     }

    override fun mapInit() {
        scrollview.visibility = View.GONE
        map.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        markerLayer = NeshanServices.createVectorElementLayer()
        lineLayer = NeshanServices.createVectorElementLayer()
        map.layers.add(markerLayer)
        map.layers.add(lineLayer)
        //set map focus position
        map.setFocalPointPosition(
            LngLat(
                dataServices.originCoordinates.second.toDouble(),
                dataServices.originCoordinates.first.toDouble()
            ), 0f
        )
        map.setZoom(16f, 0f)
        map.options.setZoomRange(Range(4.5f, 16f))

        map.layers.insert(BASE_MAP_INDEX, 
NeshanServices.createBaseMap(NeshanMapStyle.STANDARD_DAY))
        setMapBounds()
    }

    override fun drawLineGeom(org: LngLat, dest: LngLat): LineGeom {
        val lngLatVector = LngLatVector()
        lngLatVector.add(org)
        lngLatVector.add(dest)
        val lineGeom = LineGeom(lngLatVector)
        val line = Line(lineGeom, getLineStyle())
        lineLayer.add(line)
        return lineGeom
    }

    override fun drawRoute() {
        lineLayer.clear()
        for (i in 0..dataServices.routeCoordinates.count() - 2) {
            drawLineGeom(
            LngLat(dataServices.routeCoordinates[i].longitude, dataServices.routeCoordinates[i].latitude),
            LngLat(dataServices.routeCoordinates[i + 1].longitude, dataServices.routeCoordinates[i + 1].latitude)
        )
        }
    }

    override fun getLineStyle(): LineStyle {
        val builder = LineStyleCreator()
        builder.color = ARGB(2, 119, 189, 190)
        builder.width = 12f
        builder.stretchFactor = 0f
        return builder.buildStyle()
    }

    override fun setMapBounds() {
        val bounds = Bounds(
            LngLat(43.505859, 24.647017),
            LngLat(63.984375, 40.178873)
        )
        map.options.setPanBounds(bounds)
    }

    override fun showLoading() {
        distanceText.text = "Loading..."
        durationText.text = "Loading..."
    } 


    override fun showRes() {
        distanceText.text = "Distance : " + dataServices.responseDistance.getText()
    durationText.text = "Duration : " + dataServices.responseDuration.getText()
    }
}
```

Comment: might be worth making an issue on their github (assuming they have one) rather than asking here

Answer (score 1):

Review your api token and make sure you've inserted correct SHA1 in your panel